# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vineyard (from versions: none)

Tags: python, pycharm, grammar

I am trying to install the package "grammar" whose dependencies include the packages "vineyard" and "Graphviz". I am using Pycharm, and I was able to install Graphviz without any issues.

However, while installing packages "grammar" and "vineyard", I am getting the below error:

```
C:\<mylib>>pip install grammar

Collecting grammar
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/a3/4e712822d562faea9ec03f9181e53cf9dec0f4bebb1a19fceec6d3f51089/grammar-1.6-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting vineyard (from grammar)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vineyard (from grammar) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for vineyard (from grammar)
```

and

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vineyard (from versions: none)
```

When i try and install using the below command:

```
pip install C:/<mylib>/vineyard_io-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl
```

i get the below error:

```
Processing c:<mylib>\vineyard_io-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting oss2
  Downloading oss2-2.15.0.tar.gz (226 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 226 kB 544 kB/s
Collecting pyorc
  Downloading pyorc-0.4.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (765 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 765 kB 273 kB/s
Collecting s3fs
  Using cached s3fs-2021.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting pyarrow
  Downloading pyarrow-5.0.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (14.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.5 MB 159 kB/s
Collecting hdfs3
  Downloading hdfs3-0.3.1.tar.gz (44 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 44 kB 409 kB/s
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vineyard==0.2.7 (from vineyard-io) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vineyard==0.2.7
```

I am using python version 3.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after downgrading the python version to 3.8 from 3.9.
I was able to install vineyard and then grammar after that without any issues.

`pip install C:/<mylib>/vineyard_io-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using pip3 instead of pip, since your python version is 3.x.

```
pip3 install C:/<mylib>/vineyard_io-0.2.7-py3-none-any.wh
```

Please, tell me if this has worked for you. I downloaded your wheel and installed the wheel using the same python version as you, but using pip3 instead of pip.

Comment: I receive the same error even when I use pip3. 

```PS C:\<my-lib>> pip3 install C:/<my-lib>/vineyard_io-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl```
**Processing c:<mylib>\vineyard_io-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hdfs3
  Using cached hdfs3-0.3.1.tar.gz (44 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vineyard==0.2.7 (from vineyard-io) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vineyard==0.2.7**

Comment: and did you try to install it from pip/pip3 install vineyard, without the wheel?

Comment: maybe you should do a pip install --upgrade pip before downloading the vineyard module, just in case

Comment: Yes, tried them both. Still the error persists.

Comment: Then check in the official documentation for the dependencies and versions https://v6d.io/notes/install.html because it looks like a problem regarding python version and the vineyard version you're trying to use. I'd suggest you check each dependency version one by one, just to make sure you satisfy all the requirements to run it.